# Use .htaccess to setup Node.js with lamp environment

Tags: php, node.js, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a subdomain like abc.example.com which run wordpress. And its htaccess has this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

How do I make my root domain which is example.com to not use wordpress / php at all? because example.com is my suppose to be running my node.js app.

I've tried to replace line 2 with

`RewriteRule  / http://localhost:3000/$1  [P,L] but it broke my`abc.example.com

Comment: try using Express or Connect for your node.js app

Comment: @RobertBroden my node.js app is working fine before I installed wordpress on example.com, not sure why Express come into picture here

Answer (score 0):

Is Node installed on your server? Does your host support using Node? Verify that with your hosting, and if they do support Node, ask how you they can help you to configure your instance for use with Node.

If they do not, consider a hosting solution that supports Node, like Heroku or Digital Ocean.

Comment: It's not support or not, I'm using digitalocean.